# Аутентификация пользователя на внешнем сервере

Tags: android, auth

Если у меня есть сервер и на нем система авторизации, для сайтов, например, можно хранить токен в куки, а в андроиде что делать? Я знаю про firebase, но подозреваю, что просто для каждого шага отправлять HTTP запрос на сервер - это неэффективное решение, есть какие-то специальные библиотеки для этого?

К примеру, мне нужно иметь страницу с данными пользователя: его тариф, почта и т.д.
Получается надо постоянно отправлять запрос на сервер, когда пользователь заходит на этот фрагмент?

Comment: `можно хранить токен в куки, а в андроиде что делать?` - на андроиде тоже самое! вы можете получать и хранить любые нужные заголовки.

Comment: У вас есть сервер и на нем система авторизации, вот и делайте все по документации сервера. Кешируйте запросы или данные если не хотите каждый раз сервер опрашивать. https://square.github.io/retrofit/